# What is "c==0 { c=0;system("cat") }" in AWK

Tags: unix, awk

I found this command in dockerfile like below.

```
echo -e 'skip-host-cache\nskip-name-resolve' | awk '{ print } $1 == "[mysqld]" && c == 0 { c = 1; system("cat") }' /etc/my.cnf > /tmp/my.cnf
```

I couldn't undersand it.

Comment: kindly post the sample Input_file and expected output, above command working? I don't think so it is making that sense to me at least.

Comment: In addition to what I added in my previous comment, system("cat") shouldn't work as cat will require a parameter(file_name) to read it. Also system is responsible for using shell commands inside awk but it is NOT at clear and command doesn't seems to be working.

Comment: execute this command。it will add "skip-host-cache\nskip-name-resolve" to the "[mysqld]" block of my.cnf

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The `awk` program prints each line from the input file. If it finds the first line that starts with `[mysqld]`, it uses the system command `cat` to print the text from the pipe.

Personally, I would use something like this:

```
awk -v add='skip-host-cache\nskip-name-resolve' \
    '{ print } $1 == "[mysqld]" && found == 0 { print add; found = 1; }' my.cnf
```

Comment: but  i can't understand the "found == 0".

Comment: @Yaohua Any uninitialized variable will be `false`, i.e. equal to zero. Therefore, `found == 0` is true as long as we do not assign any value, which we only do after we find `[mysqld]`. So only the rule will only be applied to the first match.